# Docker "config" Container / Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to make a docker image that keeps my application configuration, so when something changes I can only change the config container and don't have to build a new image for my application.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch

RUN mkdir -p /config

ADD config.properties /config

VOLUME /config

ENTRYPOINT /bin/true
```

But it can't even create the directory. Is there a best practice for such things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that the `scratch` image is **literally completely empty**. You cannot create the directory, because there's no `/usr/bin/mkdir` executable in that image.

To create the directory anyway, you can exploit the fact that the `ADD` statement in a Dockerfile also implicitly creates directories, so the following Dockerfile should be enough:

```
FROM scratch
ADD config.properties /config/config.properties
VOLUME /config
```

Regarding the `ENTRYPOINT`; there's also no `/bin/true` in your image. This means that the container will not start (i.e. exit immediately with `exec: "/bin/true": stat /bin/true: no such file or directory`). However, as you intend to use this image for a data-only container, that's probably OK. Simply use `docker create` instead of `docker run` to create the container without starting it:

```
docker build -t config_image .
docker create --name config config_image
```

Comment: when I'm doing `docker create --name config config_image` than I get  `No command specified`

Comment: @DK1990, you probably need to use `CMD /bin/true` instead of `ENTRYPOINT /bin/true` in your Dockerfile, then.